# How do I check if a numpy dtype is integral?

Tags: python, numpy, integer, abc

How do I check if a numpy dtype is integral?  I tried:

```
issubclass(np.int64, numbers.Integral)
```

but it gives `False`.

---

Update: it now gives `True`.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Numpy has a hierarchy of dtypes similar to a class hierarchy (the scalar types actually have a bona fide class hierarchy that mirrors the dtype hierarchy).

In Numpy>2.0, you should use [`np.isdtype`](https://data-apis.org/array-api/latest/API_specification/generated/array_api.isdtype.html): `np.isdtype(np.void, 'integral')`.

Otherwise,  you can use `np.issubdtype(some_dtype, np.integer)` to test if a dtype is an integer dtype. Note that like most dtype-consuming functions, `np.issubdtype()` will convert its arguments to dtypes, so anything that can make a dtype via the `np.dtype()` constructor can be used.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.issubdtype(np.int32, np.integer)
True
>>> np.issubdtype(np.float32, np.integer)
False
>>> np.issubdtype(np.complex64, np.integer)
False
>>> np.issubdtype(np.uint8, np.integer)
True
>>> np.issubdtype(np.bool, np.integer)
False
>>> np.issubdtype(np.void, np.integer)
False
```

Alternatively, the scalar types are now registered with the appropriate `numbers` ABCs.

Comment: Just to follow up, [the upcoming numpy 1.9](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/4547) will register the scalar types with the `numbers` ABCs so `issubclass(np.int32, numbers.Integral)` will work, thanks to [Martin Teichmann](https://github.com/tecki).

Comment: `issubclass` can't take a dtype as its first argument though, as a dype is an instance of `np.dtype`. So, `np.issubdtype` might be the better option in that case

Comment: I changed my mind, and accepted this answer because it fits better with the upcoming array API standard.

Answer (score 19):

Note that `np.int64` is not a dtype, it's a Python type. If you have an actual dtype (accessed through the `dtype` field of an array), you can make use of the `np.typecodes` dict you discovered:

```
my_array.dtype.char in np.typecodes['AllInteger']
```

If you only have a type such as `np.int64`, you can first obtain a dtype that corresponds to the type, then query it as above:

```
>>> np.dtype(np.int64).char in np.typecodes['AllInteger']
True
```

Answer (score 10):

Since this question was asked, NumPy has added the appropriate registration with `numbers`, so this works:

```
issubclass(np.int64, numbers.Integral)
issubclass(np.int64, numbers.Real)
issubclass(np.int64, numbers.Complex)
```

This is more elegant than diving down to a more esoteric NumPy interface.

To perform this check on a dtype instance, use its `.type` property:

```
issubclass(array.dtype.type, numbers.Integral)
issubclass(array.dtype.type, numbers.Real)
issubclass(array.dtype.type, numbers.Complex)
```

Answer (score 8):

Building off previous answers and comments, I have settled on using the `type` attribute of the `dtype` object with Python's builtin `issubclass()` method and the `numbers` module:

```
import numbers
import numpy

assert issubclass(numpy.dtype('int32').type, numbers.Integral)
assert not issubclass(numpy.dtype('float32').type, numbers.Integral)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case the ducktyping

```
import operator
int = operator.index(number)
```

is a good method in my opinion. Plus it needs nothing numpy specific.

The only disadvantage is that in some cases you would have to `try`/`except` it.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean line 17?

```
In [13]:

import numpy as np
A=np.array([1,2,3])
In [14]:

A.dtype
Out[14]:
dtype('int32')
In [15]:

isinstance(A, np.ndarray) #A is not an instance of int32, it is an instance of ndarray
Out[15]:
True
In [16]:

A.dtype==np.int32 #but its dtype is int32
Out[16]:
True
In [17]:

issubclass(np.int32, int) #and int32 is a subclass of int
Out[17]:
True
```

Comment: Sure, but that unfortunately doesn't work for `np.int64`

Comment: Interesting, actually it only works for `int_`, `intc`, `intp` and `int32`.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Python 2?

Comment: (For me intp and int_ are int64.)

Comment: Looks like it is even platform/version dependent, I am on Win32 `Python 2.7.6`. `Numpy 1.8.1`. The document mentioned that `intc` and `intp` can be either `int32` or `int64`, I believe.